To those believing Jesus NOT to be “the only true God”: Why does God let His angels worship His firstborn, when God allows worship only of Himself?
Hebrews 1:6 (NIV) says:

when God brings his firstborn into the world, he says, “Let all God’s angels worship him.”

My question is for those who don’t believe Jesus to be “the only true God”: Why the command that the firstborn should be worshipped by God's angels, something that God said in clear terms, He only allows for Himself?
Exodus 34:14 says:

Do not worship any other god, for the Lord, whose name is Jealous, is a jealous God.

Quotes from Unitarian or Jehovah’s Witnesses sources or scholars making sense of this are welcome.

The Biblical Unitarian REV Bible says in Hebrews 1:6 "And when he again brings the firstborn into the inhabited world, he says, And let all the angels of God bow down before him."

From a Jehovah’s Witnesses point of view, here are a few points taken from an article about the subject in the Awake of April 8, 2000

First, we have to understand what Paul meant here by worship. He used
the Greek word pro·sky·neʹo. Unger’s Bible Dictionary says that this
word literally means to ‘kiss the hand of someone in token of
reverence or to do homage.’ An Expository Dictionary of New Testament
Words, by W. E. Vine, says that this word “denotes an act of
reverence, whether paid to man . . . or to God.” In Bible times
pro·sky·neʹo often included literally bowing down before someone of
high stature.
Consider the parable Jesus gave of the slave who was unable to repay a
substantial sum of money to his master. A form of this Greek word
appears in this parable, and in translating it the King James Version
says that “the servant therefore fell down, and worshipped [form of
pro·sky·neʹo] him [the king], saying, Lord, have patience with me, and
I will pay thee all.” (Matthew 18:26; italics ours.) Was this man
committing an idolatrous act? Not at all! He was merely expressing the
kind of reverence  and respect due the king, his master and superior.
Such acts of obeisance, or expressions of respect, were fairly common
in the Orient of Bible times. Jacob bowed down seven times upon
meeting his brother, Esau. (Genesis 33:3) Joseph’s brothers prostrated
themselves, or did obeisance, before him in honor of his position at
the Egyptian court. (Genesis 42:6) In this light we can better
understand what happened when the astrologers found the young child
Jesus, whom they recognized as “the one born king of the Jews.” As
rendered in the King James Version, the account tells us that they
“fell down, and worshipped [pro·sky·neʹo] him.”—Matthew 2:2, 11.
Clearly, then, the word pro·sky·neʹo, rendered “worship” in some Bible
translations, is not reserved exclusively for the type of adoration
due Jehovah God. It can also refer to the respect and honor shown to
another person. In an effort to avoid any misunderstanding, some Bible
translations render the word pro·sky·neʹo at Hebrews 1:6 as “pay him
homage” (New Jerusalem Bible), “honour him” (The Complete Bible in
Modern English), “bow down before him” (Twentieth Century New
Testament), or “do obeisance to him” (New World Translation).
Jesus Is Worthy of Obeisance
Is Jesus worthy of such obeisance? Most decidedly, yes! In his letter
to the Hebrews, the apostle Paul explains that as the “heir of all
things,” Jesus has “sat down on the right hand of the Majesty in lofty
places.” (Hebrews 1:2-4) Thus, “in the name of Jesus every knee should
bend of those in heaven and those on earth and those under the ground,
and every tongue should openly acknowledge that Jesus Christ is Lord
to the glory of God the Father.”—Philippians 2:10,11.
Outstandingly, Christ will soon use this exalted position and the
extensive executive powers that go with it to transform this earth
into a global paradise. Under God’s direction, and as a result of the
ransom sacrifice of Jesus, he will rid the world of all sadness, pain,
and sorrow for the benefit of those who submit to his righteous rule.
Is he therefore not worthy of our honor, respect, and obedience?—Psalm
2:12; Isaiah 9:6; Luke 23:43; Revelation 21:3, 4.

Some may counter that Jesus himself said “that all may honor the Son just as they honor the Father.” (John 5:23)
They may argue that honoring the Son “just as” the Father would imply the same form of worship. However, the verb “honor” (greek: timao) has the meaning of “venerate” when it is given towards a person. It means to regard someone with great respect; to revere. The level of reverence in this case is of secondary importance. You can honor or respect someone slightly more (in your heart) than you honor or respect someone else - yet you can say that you honor the one just as the other. I for instance could say: “I honor the law of the land just as I honor the relationship with my spouse.”
Me as a Jehovah’s Witness would also say: “I have tremendous love for Jesus just as I have tremendous love for Jehovah.” I honor and have great respect for both of them.
Hebrews 1:6 does support a few more JW doctrines, that I think are harder to explain from a trinitarian point of view:

The timing: the context shows a starting point where Jehovah asks his angels to subordinate to Jesus. It should happen “when He (God) again brings the firstborn into the world” (Hebrews 1:6 NKJV), which denotes Jesus’ second coming, where he started to become active as King in his inheritance of God’s Kingdom.
The command: Jehovah God officially delegates the Kingship to Jesus and makes his Angels aware that they are now accountable to Jesus. With Jehovah God  delegating His power and authority to Jesus, Jesus “has become so much better than the angels, as He has by inheritance obtained a more excellent name than they” (Hebrews 1:4)


Js.I am well aware of how the word can be used in another way as opposed to the strictly worship of God Himself. However, what your missing is the context of how worship is used. True, Hebrews 1:6 says, "And let all the angels of God worship Him." So how can it possibly mean "obeisance" when at vs8 the first word is "But." But is used to introduce a phrase or clause, contrasting with what has already been mentioned. BUT, "Thy Throne, O God is forever and ever." And if you continue reading the context you come to vs10 where the Father credits the Son with creating the heavens and the earth

It should be observed in Hebrews 1:5b that a quotation is made from 2 Samuel 7:14 and applied to the Son of God. Although that text had its first application to Solomon, the later application of it to Jesus Christ does not mean that Solomon and Jesus are the same. Jesus is “greater than Solomon” and carries out a work foreshadowed by Solomon.—Luke 11:31.
Hebrews 1:8 quotes from Psalm 45:6, which originally was addressed to a human king of Israel. Obviously, the Bible writer of this psalm did not think that this human king was Almighty. https://biblehub.com/text/psalms/45-6.htm

The text analysis of Psalm 45:6 shows that it actually says “God is your throne” and not “Your throne, O God”. Solomon, who was possibly the king originally addressed in Psalm 45, was said to sit “upon Jehovah’s throne.” In harmony with the fact that God is the “throne,” or Source and Upholder of Christ’s kingship, Daniel 7:13,14 show that God confers such authority on him.

Based on the above we see a trend that the Son has similarities with the people indicated in the verses quotes from Hebrew scripture, but is not equal with the people who were the primary subject of the Hebrew scripture. Why would it be different in Hebrew 10? Jesus was the “firstborn or all creation” and God’s instrument through which everything was created - the similarities are obvious.

You said, "Obviously, the Bible writer of this psalm did not think that this human king was Almighty." The hope of the Jewish people was the coming of a future king which was promised by God. When Jesus finally came many of the Jews did not believe the Messiah was to be God, but some did. So tell me, how do you determine who was right? Show me your exegesis of Hebrews chapter one in a way that demonstrates how you can deny the obvious of what it says? I know one way of how you did it at Colossians 1:16. You added the word "other" to the verse and "presto" God alone did not create all things

Which Jews hoped for the Messiah to be God? I’ve never heard of that. To this day, in Judaism, the Messiah is not considered to be God or a pre-existent divine Son of God. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Messiah?wprov=sfti1#. Are you really reading Hebrews 1? In the first 2 verses alone we have already 3 hints that show that Jesus cannot be God. He’s said to be like the prophets of old through whom God spoke - these prophets were NOT actually God, but their words were considered to come from God. Only “in these last days” God spoke through his Son, so where was the Son in the Hebrew scriptures?

That already on its own throws the idea that Jesus is the Angel of the Lord from the OT out the window. The next sentence tells us that God “has appointed” Jesus as “heir of all things”. How can God appoint Himself to be “heir of all things” when “everything in heaven and on earth” already belongs to Him(1 Chronicles 29:11). Vers 3 continues to show that Jesus is not God, as he‘s „the image“ or „imprint“ of God‘s being. A picture or copy of it… the mirror might show an image of me, but the image in the mirror IS NOT me. He is NOT the „Majesty on High“ but sits at His right hand.

@js witness the text in Psalms 45 bible interlinear says "your throne IS GOD"...Please show which interlinear you used for your comment please as you statement is at odds with the interlinear I'm using on biblehub.com Also, this word is used at least 4 other times in the Old Testament...its translated "your throne" in every case.

@adam - that's my point! "Your throne IS GOD" or "GOD IS your throne" (both saying the same) and NOT "Your throne, O God".  In Psalm 45, YHWH is the Source of the human king's royal office or authority. Likewise, when Paul quoted Psalm 45:6 in Hebrews 1:8, he parallels it, meaning YHWH is the Source of Jesus’ royal office or authority. YHWH gave his Son “rulership, honor, and a kingdom.” (Daniel 7:13,14) - The throne stands for authority - the king's or Jesus' authority IS GOD - as it has been given/granted by God.
